# How to design a table having age which returns current age of that person when queried after two years in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, auto-increment

I want to design a table as below, which returns the current age of a person when queried after two years.

```
CREATE TABLE Person 
(
    Person_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Initial VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Surname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Age INT NOT NULL
)
```

For example table has 2 rows

```
 Person_ID  Initial Surname Age
 -------------------------------
    1        AR     Rahman  40
    2        M      Jackson 50
```

On a select query after two years

```
select age 
from Person 
where person_ID = 1
```

it should return 42

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: "returns current age of that person when queried after two years" is not clear. Do you want `select age+2 as age`? Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. PS This will be a faq.  Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store date of birth in your table as DATE and use **computed column** without using **persisted** keyword because age calculation is **non-deterministic** as shown in the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE #Person
(
    Person_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Initial VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Surname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    DOB DATE NULL,
    Age AS DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,getdate())  
)

INSERT INTO #Person
SELECT 'Gyan','Prakash','26-feb-1994'

SELECT * FROM #Person
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store date of birth in your table and always calculate age.
To achieve this you can use calculated column or you will need include calculations in the query itself.